# How to POST data to php from JavaScript and then back into that same JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, php, post

For Example:

**file.js**

```
function math() {
    var one = 1;
    var two = 2;
    var equals = mathFunc(one,two); /*go to mathFunc and that's where the issue is*/
    var four = equals+one;
    document.write(equals);
}

mathFunc(x,y) {
    var one = x;
    var two = y;
    $.POST('file.php', {one: x,two: y});
}
```

**file.php**

```
<?php
$one = $_POST["one"];
$two = $_POST["two"];
$three = $one + $two;
?>
```

This is what I'm trying to do but not adding 1+2. Something else but it needs to happen this way.

Could I just do

```
var answer = $.POST('file.php', {one: x,two: y});
return answer;
```

---

Edit:
The data I'm using is too sensitive for GET method

Comment: you need to do `echo $three` in file.php to get any value returned from file.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the result as

```
$.POST('file.php', {one: x,two: y},function(result){
    return result;
});
```

Or even as you said

```
var result = $.POST('file.php', {one: x,two: y});
return result;
```

And in your **file.php** try to `echo` the result as

```
$one = $_POST["one"];
$two = $_POST["two"];
$three = $one + $two;
echo $three;exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to print anything in file.php in order to get the o/p.

But you are not printing, you are just calculating. so you was not getting o/p.

try

```
echo $three;
```

in file.php

Also `mathFunc()` is not returning any value.so you will not get o/p.

so return a value like this

```
var three = $.POST('file.php', {one: x,two: y});;
return three;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function math() {
    var one = 1;
    var two = 2;
    mathFunc(one,two); /* go to mathFunc and that's where the issue is */

}
function showResult(result,one){
   var four = eval(result+one);  // or sum(result,one);
   document.write(four);
}

mathFunc(x,y) {
    var one = x;
    var two = y;
    $.post('file.php', {one: x,two: y},function(result){
    showResult(result,one);
    });
```

You should do like this.